# PHP File Type Validation

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload, mime-types

I wrote the following php function to upload files but I'm having a hard time with the array of allowed file types. If I assign just one file type i.e. image/png, it works fine. If I assign more than one, its not working. I use the in_array() function to determine the allowed file types but I can't figure out how to use it properly.

Thank you!

```
function mcSingleFileUpload($mcUpFileName, $mcAllowedFileTypes, $mcFileSizeMax){
    if(!empty($mcUpFileName)){

        $mcIsValidUpload = true;

        // upload directory
        $mcUploadDir = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;

        // current file properties
        $mcFileName = $_FILES[$mcUpFileName]['name'];
        $mcFileType = $_FILES[$mcUpFileName]['type'];
        $mcFileSize = $_FILES[$mcUpFileName]['size'];
        $mcTempFileName = $_FILES[$mcUpFileName]['tmp_name'];
        $mcFileError = $_FILES[$mcUpFileName]['error'];

        // file size limit
        $mcFileSizeLimit = $mcFileSizeMax;

        // convert bytes to kilobytes
        $mcBytesInKb = 1024;
        $mcFileSizeKb = round($mcFileSize / $mcBytesInKb, 2);

        // create array for allowed file types
        $mcAllowedFTypes = array($mcAllowedFileTypes);

        // create unique file name
        $mcUniqueFileName = date('m-d-Y').'-'.time().'-'.$mcFileName;

        // if file error
        if($mcFileError > 0)
        {
            $mcIsValidUpload = false;
            mcResponseMessage(true, 'File error!');
        }

        // if no file error
        if($mcFileError == 0)
        {
            // check file type
            if( !in_array($mcFileType, $mcAllowedFTypes) ){
                $mcIsValidUpload = false;
                mcResponseMessage(true, 'Invalid file type!');
            }

            // check file size
            if( $mcFileSize > $mcFileSizeLimit ){
                $mcIsValidUpload = false;
                mcResponseMessage(true, 'File exceeds maximum limit of '.$mcFileSizeKb.'kB');
            }

            // move uploaded file to assigned directory
            if($mcIsValidUpload == true){
                if(move_uploaded_file($mcTempFileName, $mcUploadDir.$mcUniqueFileName)){
                    mcResponseMessage(false, 'File uploaded successfully!');
                }
                else{
                    mcResponseMessage(true, 'File could not be uploaded!');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//mcRequiredFile('mcFileUpSingle','please select a file to upload!');
mcSingleFileUpload('mcFileUpSingle', 'image/png,image/jpg', 2097152);
```

Comment: you would not want to use the contents of the $_FILE super global for validation, because file type and size can easily be spoofed client side. you will instead want to get the file size and type yourself using the tmp_file. you would also want to validate the file extension. basically with the above code, I could very easily upload a file that would allow me to take over most of your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$mcAllowedFTypes = array($mcAllowedFileTypes);
```

To this:

```
$mcAllowedFTypes = explode(',',$mcAllowedFileTypes);
```

Comment: No worries. FYI, to use the method you were using, you would have needed to wrap the whole line in quotes and the eval() function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the clent file type from `$_FILES` which is unsafe, get it from the file content.

Then define your allowed file types, check if the upload file type in your white list.

```
if(in_array(mime_type($file_path),$allowed_mime_types)){
    // save the file
}

$allowed_mime_types = array(
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/jpg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'video/mp4'
);


/*
For PHP>=5.3.0, you can use php's `finfo_file`([finfo_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)) function to get the file infomation about the file.

For PHP<5.3.0, you can use your's system's `file` command to get the file information.
*/
function mime_type($file_path)
{
    if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {            
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, null);
        $mime_type = $finfo->file($file_path);
    }
    if (!$mime_type && function_exists('passthru') && function_exists('escapeshellarg')) {
        ob_start();
        passthru(sprintf('file -b --mime %s 2>/dev/null', escapeshellarg($file_path)), $return);
        if ($return > 0) {
            ob_end_clean();
            $mime_type = null;
        }
        $type = trim(ob_get_clean());
        if (!preg_match('#^([a-z0-9\-]+/[a-z0-9\-\.]+)#i', $type, $match)) {
            $mime_type = null;
        }
        $mime_type = $match[1];
    }
    return $mime_type;
}
```